# How to plot data from json

Tags: pgfplots, plot, data-structures, json

Given a json file in the following format:

```
"name":"list_of_xy_values",
"data":[[1,2],[2,4],[3,6],[4,3],[5,0]]
```

I'd like to import `data` to my document to plot it with tikz/pgfplots, but I'm rather unexperienced with LaTeX.

Is there a library that can import json directly?

If a direct import is not possible, I could easily convert the desired data to a csv file with python. In this case I wonder if and how I can trigger the python script from within latex, so that the data is converted automatically when the LaTeX script compiles and without me needing to call the script manually each time.

Comment: You can do it with LuaTeX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LuaLaTeX has an integrated JSON parser.  With some wrapper code around `\pgfplotstableread` this can be used to read from a JSON file directly into a pgfplots table.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.json}
{
    "name":"list_of_xy_values",
    "data":[[1,2],[2,4],[3,6],[4,3],[5,0]]
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\expandafter\pgfplotstableread\directlua{
    local json = utilities.json.load("test.json")
    tex.sprint("{\string\r")
    tex.sprint("x y\string\r")
    for n, row in ipairs(json.data) do
        tex.sprint(row[1] .. " " .. row[2] .. "\string\r")
    end
    tex.sprint("}")
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table {\loadedtable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer! is this supposed to be a standalone example? If I try to compile this, I get an error (`! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \begin {filecontents*}{test.json}`)

Comment: @Sim Son, you need a recent LaTeX with filecontents in the kernel. Otherwise, add `\RequirePackage{filecontents}` *before* the first line

Comment: I managed to get the LaTex part to work, but I still get an error from the lua part: `[\directlua]:1: attempt to index a nil value (local 'json')`

Comment: if I change `local json` to `global json` I get the error `[\directlua]:1: syntax error near 'json'.
`

Comment: @SimSon There is no `global` keyword in Lua. Also your LaTeX seems to be ancient if it doesn't contain `filecontents`.  Better update before attempting to make this example work.

Comment: I downloaded and installed MiKTeX today and installed that package. Now the example runs if I remove `local`. Thanks for your help!