# Syntax error in LuaLaTeX \directlua code

Tags: errors, luatex, syntax, lua, directlua

I have the below document that I try to compile with LuaLaTex (using the MiKTeX package).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\expandafter\pgfplotstableread\directlua {
    global json = utilities.json.load("test.json")
    tex.sprint("{\string\r")
    tex.sprint("x y\string\r")
    for n, row in ipairs(json.data) do
        tex.sprint(row[1] .. " " .. row[2] .. "\string\r")
    end
    tex.sprint("}")
}\loadedtable

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot table {\loadedtable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I get a compilation error due to a Syntax error in the Lua part:

```
[\directlua]:1: syntax error near 'json'.
l.17 }
  \loadedtable
```

I'm a noob at LaTeX and unfortunately I have no clue of Lua either, but from what I have researched I can't figure out where there is a syntax error.

The respective `test.json` is located in the same folder like the .tex script and has this form:

```
{
    "name":"list_of_xy_values",
    "data":[[1,2],[2,4],[3,6],[4,3],[5,0]]
}
```

This question refers to [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/576669/148430)

Comment: Variables are global by default in Lua. No need to add `global` if you want to reuse `json` in further Lua calls. Just remove `global`

Comment: That was the problem, thank you! If you add a short answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in Lua are global by default, so only `local` has to be explicitly stated. See [a brief explanation on Lua Unofficial FAQ](https://www.luafaq.org/#T1.18) and [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.2) for additional info. In LuaTeX's `\directlua` and `luacode` environments is usual to define variables as local, what you can see in Henri's answer to your other question, to avoid clashes and unexpected redefinitions. :)